# Elixir Phoenix.Route.NoRouteError

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm going through the book "Programming Phoenix" and after adding the /Users/New route around page 60, my router seems to have stopped functioning properly.

When I try to navigate to any /Users route I get

"no route found for GET /Users (Rumbl.Router)"

my router.ex file looks like this:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Router do
  use Rumbl.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Rumbl do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]

  end

end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
defmodule Rumbl.UserController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller
  alias Rumbl.User

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(User)
    render conn, "index.html", users: users
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get(User, id)
    render conn, "show.html", user: user
  end

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

end
```

running "mix phoenix.routes" returns:

```
page_path  GET   /           Rumbl.PageController :index
user_path  GET   /users      Rumbl.UserController :index
user_path  GET   /users/new  Rumbl.UserController :new
user_path  GET   /users/:id  Rumbl.UserController :show
user_path  POST  /users      Rumbl.UserController :create
```

It worked fine up until adding the "new" route. I've tried removing the new route(and everything that came with it) and going back to the way it was before with just

```
get "/users", UserController, :index
get "/users/:id", UserController, :show
```

and it still doesn't work.

I've restarted the phoenix server and tried recreating the router.ex file from scratch. I'm at a loss, what could be going on here?

Here is the stack trace:

```
[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /Users (Rumbl.Router)
(rumbl) web/router.ex:1: Rumbl.Router.__match_route__/4
(rumbl) lib/phoenix/router.ex:307: Rumbl.Router.call/2
(rumbl) lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex:1: Rumbl.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
(rumbl) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: Rumbl.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
(rumbl) lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex:1: Rumbl.Endpoint.call/2
(plug_cowboy) lib/plug/cowboy/handler.ex:18: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
(cowboy) /Users/richardschmidt/Code/Elixir/rumbl/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: It helps to commit often. I see you are trying to return to "latest working" solution, but you already don't have it. It'll help you a lot to use `git` even in a most basic way.

Comment: I agree. Don't know why I didn't use git this time

Comment: I think the problem isn't with the route you are visiting in the browser, but you're referencing a non-existant route somewhere else. Can you post the full stack-trace of the error?

Comment: @Sheharyar I added the stack trace

Comment: I see that you are still visiting `/Users`. Phoenix routes are case-sensitive so you need to visit `/users`. If that still does not work, run `mix do clean, compile`, restart the server and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users` and `/users` are not the same.

Try to use downcased version of paths: `/users`, `/users/new`.

Comment: This ended up being the problem. I thought I had tried /users, but I missed the fact that my browser was autocorrecting it to /Users. Oops!